# Magento site returns large 404 page for missing images in src elements

Tags: apache, .htaccess

In `.htaccess`, we have this:

```
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

        RewriteBase /


############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

If I navigate to a non existent image on my site, by putting this url into my browser's address bar, for example `www.example.com/media/catalog/non_existent_image.jpg`, then I get a nice full 404 page as part of my site's theme. It makes sense, because it gives the user the opportunity to click the home button, or use the site's menu, while still being notified that the image they were looking for doesn't exist.

But I've found out that the same 404 page is being returned every time a `<img src='www.example.com/media/catalog/non_existent_image.jpg'>` tag appears on the page. That means every missing image causes a new instance of the entire Magento app to get fired up just to send the browser a 404 that does nothing to improve user experience. In fact it noticeably slows down page loading and adds load to the server.

How can I send back a simple HTML 404 to the browser for missing resources, while still keeping the full user experience when a user tries to navigate to a missing image with their address bar?

I'm thinking this should be solvable in `.htaccess`, rather than doing anything in Magento. Doing it in Magento would, I think, require short-circuiting the code very early, in the `index.php` file, to prevent it from doing a lot of pointless work.

Comment: I think this would be a case of only showing a normal 404 if the `HTTP_REFERER` is set to your domain - but I'm not sure, entirely.

Comment: Assuming it is possible, any idea how it would be done in htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the referrer of the resource request in order to determine whether or not it should be routed through `index.php`:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http\:\/\/example\.com\/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?:media|skin|js)/.+ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http\:\/\/example\.com\/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?:media|skin|js)/.+ index.php [L]
```

I've tested this with a REST client. When requesting a non-existent image and leaving the `HTTP_REFERER` blank, I am served the `index.php` content (in my case, a string that says "Foobar"). If I set the referrer to `http://example.com/test`, I am served with the Apache 404 ("Object Not Found").

I've included the `RewriteEngine` directive here to imply that these should really be the first checks made, before anything else is done.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without hard coding the referrer?  The htaccess is preferably portable to other servers with different domain names. I edited my question to ad the top of my rewrite section where I have `RewriteBase` one more `RewriteRule` than in my earlier edit. I'm not in a CGI environment, though.

Comment: You could check to see whether or not it is blank (`!^$` for the first one and `^$` for the second). Note that it's in reverse. Haven't tested, but I think it'll work.